# Linux find all files in sub directories and move them

Tags: linux, recursion, move

I have a Linux-System where some users put files with ftp in a Directory. In this Directory there are sub-directories which the users can create. Now I need a script that searches for all files in those subdirectories and moves them in a single Directory (for backup). The Problem: The Sub directories shouldn´t be removed.

the directory for the users is /files/media/documents/
and the files have to be moved in the Directory /files/dump/. I don´t care about files in /files/media/documents/, they are already handled by another script.

I already tried this script:

```
for dir in /files/media/documents/
do
    find "$dir/" -iname '*' -print0 | xargs -0 mv -t /files/dump/
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of iterating, you could just use find. In man-page there is a "-type" option documented, so for moving *only files* you could do:

```
find "/files/media/documents/" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 mv -t /files/dump/
```

You also won't like to find files in /files/media/documents/, but all sub-directories? Simply add "-mindepth":

```
find "/files/media/documents/" -type f -mindepth 1 -print0 | xargs -0 mv -t /files/dump/
```

---

Alternatively you could also use "-exec" to skip a second command (xargs):

```
find "/files/media/documents/" -type f -mindepth 1 -exec mv {} /files/dump/ \;
```

Comment: I also found another way:
for dir in /files/media/documents/*
do
 mv $dir/* /files/dump/
done
this seems to work, too

Comment: Thats correct too, but it won't work with directories in your subdirectories and will also move those sub-sub-directories. If that doesn't matter, than your for-loop will do the same ;-)

Comment: i don´t care about sub-sub-directories because if they even exist, they have to be moved, too :-)